# Как в scrapy осуществить переход на след страницу?

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

Здравствуйте пишу парсер новостей на scrapy, мне нужно что бы он начинал парсить со стартового url открывал каждую новость извлекал данные, дальше переходил на след страницу и проделывал все тоже самое. У меня парсит только первую, а дальше идти не хочет(

```
class GuardianSpider(CrawlSpider):
 name = 'guardian'
 allowed_domains = ['theguardian.com']
  start_urls = ['https://www.theguardian.com/world/europe-news']

  rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='u-cf index-page']",),
              allow=('https://www.theguardian.com/\w+/\d+/\w+/\d+/\w+',)),
    callback = 'parser_items'),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='u-cf index-page']",),
              allow=('https://www.theguardian.com/\w+/\w+?page=\d+',)),
    follow = True),
)
```

Comment: через API типа http://open-platform.theguardian.com не доступна нужная вам информация?

Comment: Я парсю не только гарден, это в качестве примера взял

Comment: тогда в чём проблема? Не можете найти рабочий пример CrawlSpider?

Comment: Не могу сделать что бы от переходил на след. страницу. Получаеться, что он открывает начальную далее заходит в каждую статью, вытаскивает текст,потом мне нужно перейти на след страницу, а он не переходит